# How to change background color of number picker in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-number-picker

Code:

```
<NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numer_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

It is taking `black color by default`. How can I change that?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

```
<NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numer_picker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:solidColor="#2E1E91" />
```

Use

> android:solidColor="#your_color"

to change the default color.

Answer (score 2):

Try out those 2 things:

Either try to change the background color:

```
android:background="#EEEEEE"
```

Or use the solidColor for styling it:

```
android:solidColor="#EEEEEE"
```

Answer (score 1):

change background of number picker using color or you can use multiple color by drawable.

for single background color use

```
  android:background="@color/colorAccent"
```

and  for gradient or stylish background use

```
  android:background="@drawable/background_change"
```

and background_change.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
 <gradient
    android:startColor="#707070"
    android:centerColor="#f8f8f8"
    android:endColor="#707070"
    android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

use below to change default color to any color you want,

```
android:background="your color here"
```

example: `android:background="#71BF45 "`